# How to save a response to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, mongoid

I am trying to save this response from an API to a model field. I cant save it because mongoid is saying this is not a string. I tried saving it as an Array and as a Hash. No luck.

How can I properly save this in a field or properly format it so I can save it as an array or hash so I can call it later.I thought maybe something like this but it doesn't feel right.

```
transactions.rb

    field :accounts,        type: Array.new
    ...

    def account_pull
       accounts_response = Api.set_user(access_token, ['auth'])    
       self.accounts = accounts_response.accounts
       model.save
    end
end
```

Here is a sample of the full response that I am getting.

```
#<Api::User:0xb7e9f2c @accounts=[#<Api::Account:0xb7b6eb0 @id="QPO8Jo8vdDHMepg41PBwckXm4KdK1yUdmXOwK", @name=nil, @type="depository", @meta={"number"=>"9606", "name"=>"Bank Savings"}, @institution_type="fake_institution", @available_balance=1203.42, @current_balance=1274.93, @subtype=nil, @numbers={"routing"=>"021000021", "account"=>"9900009606", "wireRouting"=>"021000021"}>, #<Api::Account:0xb7b6ba4 @id="nban4wnPKEtnmEpaKzbYFYQvA7D7pnCaeDBMy", @name=nil, @type="depository", @meta={"number"=>"1702", "name"=>"Bank Checking"}, @institution_type="fake_institution", @available_balance=1081.78, @current_balance=1253.32, @subtype=nil, @numbers={"routing"=>"021000021", "account"=>"9900001702", "wireRouting"=>"021000021"}>, #<Api::Account:0xb7b68e8 @id="XARE85EJqKsjxLp6XR8ocg8VakrkXpTXmRdOo", @name=nil, @type="depository", @meta={"number"=>"5204", "name"=>"Bank Premier Checking"}, @institution_type="fake_institution", @available_balance=7205.23, @current_balance=7255.23, @subtype=nil, @numbers={"routing"=>"021000021", "account"=>"9900005204", "wireRouting"=>"021000021"}>, #<Api::Account:0xb7b66cc @id="pJPM4LMBNQFrOwp0jqEyTwyxJQrQbgU6kq37k", @name=nil, @type="credit", @meta={"limit"=>12500, "number"=>"3002", "name"=>"Bank Credit Card"}, @institution_type="fake_institution", @available_balance=9930, @current_balance=2275.58, @subtype=nil, @numbers={}>], @transactions=[], @permissions=["auth"], @access_token="test_chase", @api_res="success", @info={}, @pending_mfa_questions="", @type=nil>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is neither a String nor an Array or a Hash: it's an API::User with an Array of API::Account.

Maybe transforming it to a simple struct using as_json will do the trick:

```
model.user = api_user.as_json
model.save
```

Alternatively, you may try and get the initial response, to avoid many transformations (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

change accounts field type to hash

```
class Transactions
  include Mongoid::Document
  field : accounts :type => Hash
end
```

Then you can save the response after converting to hash

```
  def account_pull
   response = Api.set_user(access_token, ['auth'])
   accounts = response.accounts
   accounts_hash = Hash[accounts.map.with_index { |x, i| [i, x] }]
   self.accounts = accounts_hash
   self.save
 end
```